# Update records in elasticsearch-laravel;

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I want to update record of elasticsearch. I am passing whole record in $data to elasticsearch for update.

**Update code :**

```
public function updateEs($data)
    {
        $params = array();
        $params['index'] = \App::environment();
        $params['type'] = $data['context'];
        $model = new \Modules\Catalog\Repositories\ProductRepo;

        $form = $model->loadProduct($data['id']);// whole data come from database 
        $data=(object)$form; //array to object
        
            $data['body'] = $data;
            $data['index'] = 'my_index';
            $data['type'] = 'product';
            $data['id' ]= $data['id'];
        
        $response = \Es::update($data);
    }
```

**But I am getting ERROR :**

> FatalErrorException in ElasticSearchHelper.php line 121:
>
> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Answer (score 0):

You cast `$form` to `stdClass` with `(object)`. Then you treat it as an `array` by doing `$data['stuff']`. To solve the error you should do for example:

```
$data->body = $data;
```

I don't know if this is the only error and if your ES will work now, but it should solve the error you mention.

Comment: Thanks sir i want to know one thing may i pass whole record while update elasticsearch record?

Comment: In above example $form is an array i am converting in object in $data=(object)$form; should I ?

Comment: That depends on if ES::update() expects an array or object (I dont know the function, just what caused the error)

Comment: Hello sir, I did as you said in your answer but still same error.

Comment: Did you debug? `echo gettype($form);` will not result in "array" then.

Comment: yes i have printed the result. and $form is an in array format